# Using an outer join with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. My lists look like this:

**AvailableFlavors**

```
ID  Name
--  ----
1   Vanilla
2   Chocolate
3   Strawberry
4   Rocky Road
5   Cookies and Cream
```

**FavoriteFlavors**

```
ID  Name
--  ----
1   Vanilla
3   Strawberry
```

How do I get a list of `AvailableFlavors` that are NOT in the list of `FavoriteFlavors` using LINQ? Currently I have:

```
List<Flavor> AvailableFlavors = GetAvailableFlavors();
List<Flavor> FavoriteFlavors = GetFavoriteFlavors();

AvailableFlavors = from availableFlavor in AvailableFlavors
                   // what goes here?
                   select availableFlavor;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple LINQ [`.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) call will do the trick:

```
List<Flavor> AvailableFlavors = GetAvailableFlavors();
List<Flavor> FavoriteFlavors = GetFavoriteFlavors();
var availableButNotFavoriteFlavors = AvailableFloavors.Except(FavoriteFlaovors);
```

The result is `IEnumerable<Flavor>`, so you might need convert back to List.

**Edit**: The real question I guess is how to write a custom `IEqualityComparer` which we use in `.Except' method. This [.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation page has a good  example of write a simple comparer.

If you can't be bothered doing that, an alternative option is just use `.Where` and manually compare properties:

```
var availableButNotFavoriteFlavors =
    AvailableFloavors
        .Where(af => !FavoriteFlavors.Any(ff => af.Id == ff.ID && af.Name == ff.Name);
```

Comment: Oh man! That is so cool. I had no idea the `Except` option even existed. That's great!

Answer (score 0):

With your custom class `Flavor` I overrode the `Equals()` and `ToString()` and did the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Flavor> availableFlavors = new List<Flavor> () {
            new Flavor() { ID = 1, Name = "Vanilla" },
            new Flavor() { ID = 2, Name = "Chocolate" },
            new Flavor() { ID = 3, Name = "Strawberry" },
            new Flavor() { ID = 4, Name = "Rocky Road" },
            new Flavor() { ID = 5, Name = "Cookies and Cream"}
        };

        List<Flavor> favoriteFlavors = new List<Flavor>() {
            new Flavor() { ID = 1, Name = "Vanilla" },
            new Flavor() { ID = 3, Name = "Strawberry" },
        };

        availableFlavors.Where(f => !favoriteFlavors.Contains(f))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
    }
}

public class Flavor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Flavor objToCheck = obj as Flavor;
        if (objToCheck != null)
        {
            if (objToCheck.ID == ID &&
                objToCheck.Name == Name)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("ID: {0} Name: {1}", ID, Name);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
ID: 2 Name: Chocolate
ID: 4 Name: Rocky Road
ID: 5 Name: Cookies and Cream
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1Qpzt)

Comment: This is technically correct but there is no need to modify the class structure to accomplish a simple filtering.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Select Name from favorite flavors
var favoriteFlavorNames = from favoriteFlavor in GetFavoriteFlavors()
                          select favoriteFlavor.Name;

// Find available flavors not in favorite flavors
var filteredAvailbleFlavors = from availableFlavor in GetAvailableFlavors()
                              where !favoriteFlavorNames.Contains(availableFlavor.Name)
                              select availableFlavor;
```

Or you can combine the two into:

```
var filteredAvailbleFlavors = from availableFlavor in GetAvailableFlavors()
                              let favoriteFlavorNames = 
                                  (from favoriteFlavor in GetFavoriteFlavors()
                                   select favoriteFlavor.Name)
                              where !favoriteFlavorNames.Contains(availableFlavor.Name)
                              select availableFlavor;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
AvailableFlavors.Where(af => !FavoriteFlavors.Any(ff => af.Name == ff.Name));
```

Comment: This is wrong because you cannot assume OP has overridden `Equals` for `Flavor`

Comment: That's true, but not knowing what the Flavor object contains, makes it difficult to give the exact code. Why wouldn't this work if he implements the ==? This should be taken as pseudocode given the details provided above. Why did you downvote this?

Comment: You have basically answered your own question. I downvoted your answer because you are **assuming** the implementation of `Flavor` without any explanation in your answer